# Search a strict value in a Solr multivalued search

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have indexed documents with a multivalued field.

I need to search for those documents with only one specific value and only this value even it is repeated.

Example of document to found:

```
<doc>
<arr name="source">
      <str>X</str>
</arr>
</doc>
```

Example of document NOT to be found:

```
<doc>
<arr name="source">
      <str>X</str>
      <str>Y</str>
</arr>
</doc>
```

Could the search be like. source:X and -source:"anything else"... ? or strict search of a word?.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work on the count of the multivalued field.
However, There is no function query to work on the count of the field.
So you would need to either store the count of the field from the client side or probably check the [AAA](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html) to add it automatically so that you can query `source:X AND length=1`

Comment: I do the same but I was trying to look for a better solution if it exists because I thought what I do is not the best. Thank you for proving once again - "Trust yourself". ;)